# Limit divergence test

Tags: limits, divergent-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3^n-1}{3^{n+1}}$$

The answer to this is that it diverges but I have no idea how to take the limit of this.

It looks like if we direct sub in $n = \infty$ it will be $3^{\infty}$ which I have never learned.

Can anyone explain how to take the limit of this problem?

Comment: The terms do not have limit $0$, in fact they have limit $1/3$, so the series diverges. Try to avoid thinking in terms of "substituting" $\infty$.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you give some hints, How would it be 1/3?

Comment: If you divide top and bottom of the $n$-th term by $3^n$, you get $\dfrac{1-1/3^n}{3+1/3^n}$. Now it is easy to see what happens as  $n\to\infty$. Less precisely, but useful for the intuition, for large $n$ the top is "about" $3^n$ and the bottom is "about" $3^{n+1}$.

Comment: Also, "direct sub in $n=\infty$" doesn't make mathematical sense. Infinity is not a number.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I haven't really done sum problems other than geometric sums but I can do the limit...
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{3^x-1}{3^{x+1}}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1-\frac{1}{3^x}}{\frac{3^{x+1}}{3^{x}}}$$
Divide top and bottom by $3^x$. This is the trick when solving limits which goes to infinity.

Note that $\frac{a^m}{a^n}=a^{m-n}$ so $\frac{3^{x+1}}{3^x}=3^{x+1-x}=3$
Now back to the other equation.
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1-\frac{1}{3^x}}{\frac{3^{x+1}}{3^{x}}}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1-\frac{1}{3^x}}{3}$$
$3^x$ goes to infinity so $\frac{1}{3^x}$ goes to 0.
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1-\frac{1}{3^x}}{3}=\frac{1-0}{3}$$
The sequence converges to $\frac{1}{3}$ but it's sum diverges as you know